# Django multi-level extends not appearing

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

With Django 1.10 I am building a blog/portfolio hybrid website. Besides Mysite, I have two apps, Blog and Portfolio. Within blog/templates/ I have an index.html that displays content from both Blog and Portfolio (the 15 most recent blog posts and 5 most recent portfolio projects).

So the index.html page looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7bEj.jpg

As you can see data is not appearing. However, it does when I navigate to the Blog page and Portfolio page. For example, the Blog page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU7jl.jpg

I am figuring that this issue is related to the mult-level extends that I have going on. Because the Blog and Portfolio pages both display content from the database, it makes me think that the models are O.K but something is up with the views. The index.html extends the base_generic.html template, and my recent_blog_posts.html and recent_portfolio_pieces.html extends the index.html.

I am not sure how to remedy this issue. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

**Project structure**

```
mysite/
---blog/
------static/
---------css/
---------images/
------------blogpostimages/
------------favicon.ico
------templates/
---------blog/
------------blog_post.html
------------blog_list.html
------------recent_blog_posts.html
---------base_generic.html
---------index.html
---------bio.html
---------resume.html
------admin.py
------apps.py
------models.py
------tests.py
------urls.py
------views.py
---portfolio/
------static/
---------css/
---------images/
------------portfoliopieceimages/
------templates/
---------portfolio/
------------portfolio_piece.html
------------portfolio_list.html
------------recent_portfolio_pieces.html
------admin.py
------apps.py
------models.py
------tests.py
------urls.py
------views.py
---mysite/
------settings.py
------urls.py
------wsgi.py
manage.py
db.sqlite3
requirements.txt
```

**blog/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.

from .models import Blog


def index(request):
     """
     View function for home page of site.
     """
    # Generate most recent blog post

    title = Blog.objects.all()
    post_date = Blog.objects.all()
    get_absolute_url = Blog.objects.all()
    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable.

    return render(
          request,
         'index.html',
    context={'title': title,
              'post_date': post_date,
              'get_absolute_url': get_absolute_url,
              }
 )


def recent_blog_posts.html(request):
     blog = Blog.objects.order_by('-post_date')[0:11]
     return render(request, 'index.html', {'blog': blog})


class BlogListView(generic.ListView):
    """
    Generic class-based view for a list of blog posts.
    """
    model = Blog
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.order_by('-post_date')


class BlogDetailView(generic.DetailView):
"""
Generic class-based detail view for a blog post.
"""
model = Blog


def bio(request):
return render(
    request, 'bio.html'
)


def resume(request):
return render(
    request, 'resume.html'
)
```

**index.html**

```
<div>

<h2>Recent Blog Posts</h2>

        <div>

            {% block blogs %}


            {% if blog_list %}

              {% for blog in blog_list %}
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h4><small>{{blog.post_date}} » </small><a href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">{{ blog.title }}</a></h4>
                    </header>
                </article>
              {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
              <p>Unfortunately, there are no blog posts yet.</p>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
{% endblock %}

    </div>


    <div>

        <h2>Portfolio</h2>

         {% if portfolio %}

              {% for portfolio in portfolio %}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="{{ portfolio.get_absolute_url }}">
                        {% load static %}
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ portfolio.cover_image }}" alt="">
                        <p>{{ portfolio.title }}</p>
                        <p>{{ portfolio.client_name }}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
        <div>
           <p>Unfortunately, there are no portfolio pieces yet.</p>
        </div>

            {% endif %}
```

Comment: In your template your are using `blog_list` context variable. But in your index view, the context return doesn't containt this variable. You have title, post_date, and get_absolute_url. Same thing for the variable `portofolio` in this template. PS: Fix indent of your code pls

Comment: @Wilfried thank you! this worked, if you turn it into an answer I will choose it

Comment: Done. Glad to help you. And be rigorous. It is the asset of a good developer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the variable pass to your context, in your template.
So you have to pass the variable `blog_list` to your context to iterate on it in your template.

Example below: (only for `blog_list`)

```
def index(request):
    """
    View function for home page of site.
    """
    blog_list  = Blog.objects.all()
    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable.
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'blog_list': blog_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to the template in the context. I don't really understand what you're trying to do in the *index* by setting and passing the variables in the context:

```
# Generate most recent blog post

title = Blog.objects.all()
post_date = Blog.objects.all()
get_absolute_url = Blog.objects.all()
```

Blog.objects.all() returns a queryset with all blog instances, not a title/post_date/get_absolute_url of a single blog instance.

In the template you refer to two context variables: blog_list and portfolio. You don't set the variables in the *index*. I would also avoid a statement like that:

```
{% for portfolio in portfolio %}
```

Don't use the same variable name as the variable you iterate over, change the latter to *portfolio* or *portfolio_list*.

To make it work you might try this:

**index.py**

```
def index(request):
  blog_list = Blog.objects.all()
  portfolio_list = Portfolio.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'index.html',
    context={'blog_list': blog_list, 'portfolio_list': portfolio_list}
  )
```

In the **index.html** file change:

```
{% for portfolio in portfolio %}
```

to

```
{% for portfolio in portfolio_list %}
```

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean. I just tried to implement your suggestion, but I think I have some db adjustments to do before it works. Do you know why it's bad form to use the same variable name as the variable I iterate over? (I am new to Django and Python in general)

Comment: I am not sure how it works in template but in a python code it would change the value of the portfolio variable to the last iterated value after the loop ended.